# await/async and going outside the box

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have a question regarding await/async and using async methods in slightly different scenarios than expected, for example not directly awaiting them. For example, Lets say I have two routines I need to complete in parallel where both are async methods (they have awaits inside). I am using `await TAsk.WhenAll(...)` which in turn expects some sort of list of tasks to wait for. What I did is something like this:

```
            await Task.WhenAll(new Task[]
            { 
                Task.Run(async () => await internalLoadAllEmailTargets()),
                Task.Run(async () => await internalEnumerateInvoices())
            });
```

This seems overly elaborate to me, in the sense that I am creating async tasks whose sole purpose is to invoke another task. Can't I just use tasks which are returned from the async method state engine? Yet, I am failing to do that since compiler treats every direct mention of async method as an invocation point:

```
            // this doesn't seem to work ok
            await Task.WhenAll(new Task[]
            { 
                internalLoadAllEmailTargets(),
                internalEnumerateInvoices()
            });
```

If its like this, it seems to synchronously calls one after another, and if I place await in front of methods, it is no longer a Task. Is there some rule book on how async methods should be handled outside plain await?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every `async` method starts executing synchronously, but when it hits its first `await`, it may behave asynchronously. So this line:

```
await Task.WhenAll(internalLoadAllEmailTargetsAsync(), internalEnumerateInvoicesAsync());
```

should work just fine. It is roughly equivalent to this:

```
var _1 = internalLoadAllEmailTargetsAsync();
var _2 = internalEnumerateInvoicesAsync();
await Task.WhenAll(_1, _2);
```

If your methods are truly asynchronous, then this should be fine.

Now, if your methods are actually doing some synchronous work - say, heavy CPU-bound code - then you may want to use `Task.Run` to invoke them (if your calling code is on a UI thread).

Comment: Ah, ok, this actually makes sense. What if I have `async Task<something>`, so I need to pick up the results of multiple async method calls?

Comment: @mmix: If both tasks are the same type (e.g., `Task<Something>`), then you can do `Something[] results = await Task.WhenAll(...);`

Comment: Well, they are not. I guess no going around the delegates for those.

Comment: @mmix: If they're not, then you can do `var targetsTask = internalLoadAllEmailTargetsAsync(); var invoicesTask = internalEnumerateInvoicesAsync(); await Task.WhenAll(emailTask, invoicesTask); var targets = await targetsTask; var invoices = await invoicesTask;`

Answer (score 1):

You have some code, which creates `Task` object, and it will be invoked as usual, i.e synchronously. Control will be returned to the invoking code only after `Task` creation and in case of `async` it will be after the first `await`. 
So, if it's a problem, that some part of your method will be invoked in blocking manner, you could use `Task.Yield` at the beginning, just be careful with `SynchronizationContext` and thread switches.

But in most cases there is nothing wrong with that scenario, because code, which creates `Task`, is small and fast, while actual timing is caused by some sort of IO operation.